# PassportJS deserializeUser never called

Tags: node.js, session, passport.js

I've got Passport setup to authenticate users stored in mongodb. Seems to work fine: authentication succeeds/fails appropriately and session variables get set. However, getting Passport to check for a session is failing. Something seems to be quite wrong in that the console.log statements I've added to the `deserializeUser` callback never see the light of day. I assume my problem is related to `deserializeUser` never being called. Anyone able to diagnose my misstep?

```
// Passport configuration
passport.serializeUser(function(user, cb){ cb(null, user.id) });
passport.deserializeUser(function(uid, cb){
  console.log("Trying to deserialize user: "+uid);
  User.findById(uid, function(err, user){
    cb(err, user);
  });
});
// auth strategy function
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({usernameField: 'email'},
  function(email, pass, done){
    User.findOne({email: email}, function (err, user) {
      if (err)
        return done(err);
      if (!user)
        return done(null, false, {message: "Couldn't find user"});
      var crypted = bcrypt.hashSync(pass, user.salt);
      if(user.hashpass != crypted)
        return done(null, false, {message: "Bad password"});
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));

passport.CreateSession =  function (req, res, next) {
  passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info){
    if(err || !user)
      return res.json({status: "Failure: "+err});
    req.logIn(user, function (err){
      if(err)
        return res.json({status: "Failure: "+err});
      return res.json({status: "Authenticated"});
    });
  })(req, res, next);
};
```

with the following in app.js:

```
app.post('/session', passport.CreateSession); // restify better
app.del('/session', passport.DestroySession);
app.get('/images', passport.CheckSession, routes.images);
```

Answer (score 53):

For anyone else who is having this issue, take a look at this:

```
app.use(session({ 
    secret: 'something', 
    cookie: { 
        secure: true
    }}));
```

If you have `cookie.secure` set to true and you're NOT using SSL (i.e. https protocol) then the cookie with the session id is not returned to the browser and everything fails silently. Removing this flag resolved the problem for me - it took hours to realise this!

Comment: Dave, is session here "express-session"? can you make that clear.

Comment: This was the issue for me, and it took 2 work days to find this answer...
Thanks!

Comment: Thank you very much. Same thing for me. Serialize user was being called, but never deserialize. No cookies present in the browser, and nothing in req.session.passport. Flipping this flag seemed to help. Even though locally it was working, on my prod instance which is running on Heroku and using their free SSL, it didn't want to set the secure cookie.

Answer (score 29):

If you are using the `authenticate` callback when you authenticate with passport you need to log the user in manually. It will not be called for you.

```
passport.authenticate('local', function (err, user) {
    req.logIn(user, function (err) { // <-- Log user in
       return res.redirect('/'); 
    });
})(req, res);
```

Comment: From passport's docs: `Note: passport.authenticate() middleware invokes req.login() automatically. This function is primarily used when users sign up, during which req.login() can be invoked to automatically log in the newly registered user.`

Comment: You might want to recheck that, if you are doing auth manually it will not be called.

Comment: How does it relate to *deserializeUser never being called* issue?

Comment: `console.log(err.message)` after `req.logIn(user, function (err) {` show: `Failed to serialize user into session` ?

Comment: In the passport docs about the custom callback in `authenticate`: `The callback can use the arguments supplied to handle the authentication result as desired. Note that when using a custom callback, it becomes the application's responsibility to establish a session (by calling req.login()) and send a response.`

Answer (score 13):

Have you `use()`'d `passport.session()` middleware?  Like in this example:

https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/v1.0.0/examples/login/app.js#L91

That's what restores the session and calls `deserializeUser`, so it sounds like that may be missing.

Comment: Jared - thanks for helping out. Yep, I've got  app.use(passport.session()); in app.js

Comment: This is node 0.8.0, express 2.5.10, and the latest passport, btw.

Comment: Hmm, and I'm assuming you have your sessions properly set up and persisted too?  If so, I don't see anything obvious.  Here's my suggestion: 1. Try running under node 0.6.x, to see if there's an incompatibility somewhere with 0.8.  2. Post a runnable, copy-n-paste gist, and I'll run it and see what I can find.

Comment: Jared - I'm using express.cookieParser(), express.session({secret: 'somethingsecret'}), and passport.session()... anything else I'm missing? Did try it with node 0.6.0 and no joy. If that session setup looks proper and you don't see anything else, I'll post a gist later on this evening. Thanks so much for your help - the node community really benefits from folks like yourself aiding users.

Comment: Gist is here: https://gist.github.com/3030629 ...I didn't include the user model in the gist, but it's a straightforward mongo document with a bcrypted password and email field. The execution gets nowhere near it, so I didn't think it was critical - if you disagree, let me know and I'll update.

Comment: I'm not having any troubles with your gist.  `deserializeUser` gets called and the `CheckSession` function `next()`s as expected.  Are you using cluster or load balancing?  That could cause a request to bounce to a different server, and you'll need to switch to something besides the MemoryStore for sessions (see connect-redis).

Comment: Other than that, I'm out of ideas.  Can you run the example in passport-local?  If that works, I'd start stripping things down until you isolate the point that is going wrong.  Let me know what you discover.

Comment: Jared, no cluser, no load balancer, and the passport-local example works perfectly. Very strange. I'll continue to poke around, and if I find something, I'll let you know.

Comment: Fixed it. Seems that my version of Mongoose won't allow me to access document fields from the strategy definition without using .get() ...not sure how that didn't throw an error somewhere, but that seems to get me up and running. +1 for looking into it!

Comment: Also, `passport.session()` should be below/after the `app.use(session…`

Answer (score 10):

Okay, this took me almost 3 days to solve, which seems to be a simple fix, at least in my case. I had to place:

```
app.use(require('cookie-parser'));
```

and

```
app.use(require('express-session')({
    secret: 'keyboard cat',
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));
```

BEFORE calling:

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

**Note:** These snippets are not my actual code, I have taken it from [GitHub](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-local-example/blob/master/server.js), but that is the gist of it.

Answer (score 4):

Today I faced the same issue, and in my case the cause was how the client side makes the API calls. And the following approach helped me to overcome the problem:

```
const doFetch(url, method = 'GET', body) {
  const headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  headers.append('Accept', 'application/json');
  headers.append('Cache', 'no-cache');
  const params = { 
    method, headers, 
    credentials: 'include' // The cookie must be sent!
  }
  if(body) {
    params.body = body;
  }
  return fetch(url, params);
}
```

After this, `deserializeUser` began to be called properly.

Comment: This put me on the correct solution, in my case, using Axios, I had to make my call with `axios.get(route, {withCredentials: true})`

Answer (score 4):

In my case it was because I had this code:

```
app.get("/auth/google/callback", 
    passport.authenticate("google", { 
        failureRedirect: "/admin/login/?error",
    }),
    (req, res) => {
        return res.redirect("/admin/");
    },
);
```

Apparently in this case req.login() will not be called (which calls deserialize). I changed it to this and it worked:

```
app.get("/auth/google/callback", 
    passport.authenticate("google", { 
        successRedirect: "/admin/", 
        failureRedirect: "/admin/login/?error",
    })
);
```

Comment: i tried this and it didn't work but then i made a bunch of random changes and it still didn't work and then i tried this again and it worked... computer science moment i guess

Answer (score 1):

I fought the same problem the entire day. I had a custom callback set up to do authorizations (like at the bottom of http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/). It looks like Passport preprocesses all request objects before they even hit the other middleware (based on some logging statements I wrote). As part of that preprocessing, it places the deserialized user information into the request.user object. Unfortunately, the default behavior of passport.authenticate ('local', callback) seems to be to ignore any session or cookie data, and instead assume that the username and PW are being sent in the request object. What I did to fix this was to first check the request.user object, and if it existed, it meant that Passport had done its preprocessing and then I could call login directly. Here is my authorization function, which I use in place of passport.authenticate('local'):

```
function doAuth(request, response, next)
{ 

if (request.user) {
    request.logIn(request.user, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            response.status(500).json({message:
                    "Login failed. Auth worked. Nonsense"});
            return;
        }
        console.log("doAuth: Everything worked.");
        next();
    });
    return;
}

passport.authenticate('local', function(err, user, info) {
    if (err) {
        response.status(500).json({message: "Boo Passport!"});
        return; //go no further
        //until I figure out what errors can get thrown
    }
    if (user === false) {
        console.log("Authentication failed. Here is my error:");
        console.log(err);
        console.log("Here is my info:");
        console.log(info);
        response.status(500).json({message: "Authentication failed."});
        return;
    }
    request.logIn(user, function(err) {
        if (err) {
        console.log("Login failed. This is the error message:");
        console.log(err);
        response.status(500).json({message:"Login failed."});
            return;
        }
        console.log("doAuth: Everything worked. I don't believe it.");

        next();
    });
})(request, response, next);

 }
```

Comment: Your explanation helped me a lot thanks! I have not applied your solution but you pointed out the problem though :D

Answer (score 1):

In **Heroku**, all requests come into the application as plain http, but with the X-Forwarded-Proto header to know whether the original request was http or https.

That causes express to see non-ssl traffic and so it refuses to set a secure cookie when running on Heroku. You have to tell express to trust the information in that header by setting 'trust proxy'.

```
app.set('trust proxy', 1);
```

right before

```
app.use(session...
```

might work for you if you're having trouble with this on Heroku specifically. If your cookies/session are messed up then that could be why deserialize is not being called.

Answer (score 0):

in my case, I've placed

```
app.use(cookieSession({
  maxAge : 60*60*1000,
  keys : [key.cookieSession.key1]
}));
```

above

```
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue while using [JamStack architecture](https://umbraco.com/knowledge-base/jamstack/) (client-side rendering instead of server-side) and none of the existing answers were useful.

### Backend (localhost:4000)

The most important part is the CORS setup:

```js
const cors = require("cors");
const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
  credentials: true, // ! important
  methods: ["GET", "POST"],
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

app.use(logger("dev"));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));

const sessionMiddleware = session({
  secret: process.env.SESSION_SECRET || "random-secret",
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: true,
});
// ! order of middlewares below is important
app.use(sessionMiddleware);
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Dealing with login:

```js
router.post("/login", (req, res, next) => {
  passport.authenticate("local", (err, user, info) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err);
    }
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).send(info);
    }
    req.login(user, (err) => { // ! important
      if (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: "Login failed." });
      }
      res.status(200).send();
    });
  })(req, res, next);
});
```

**The `req.login()` part is essential.**

The above route will authenticate a user. If successfully verified, Passport will call the `serializeUser` function. When the session is authenticated, Passport will call the `deserializeUser` function and the `req.user` property is then set. (https://www.passportjs.org/concepts/authentication/sessions/)

For the sake of completeness, here's my passport setup:

```js
passport.use(
  new LocalStrategy(
    {
      // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34511021/passport-js-missing-credentials
      usernameField: "email",
      passwordField: "password",
    },
    async (email, password, done) => {
      console.log(email, password);

      try {
        const user = await User.findOne({ email });
        if (!user) {
          return done(null, false, { error: "Email does not exist." });
        }
        console.log("User valid");

        const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password);

        if (!match) {
          console.log("Passwords invalid");
          // passwords do not match!
          return done(null, false, { error: "Invalid password." });
        }
        console.log("Passwords valid");
        return done(null, user);
      } catch (err) {
        return done(err);
      }
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  console.log(`serializeUser: ${user}`);

  done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(async (id, done) => {
  console.log(`deserializeUser: ${id}`);

  try {
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    console.log(user);

    done(null, user);
  } catch (err) {
    done(err);
  }
});
```

### Frontend (localhost:3000)

On the login page of my frontend, I had to include `credentials: "include"` when making a POST request to the API:

```js
      const response = await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/auth/login`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
        credentials: "include", // ! important
        body: JSON.stringify(values),
      });
```

**Each time the frontend communicates with the backend via the API**, I had to include `credentials: "include"` in my request. For example, on another page of my frontend which is only available to authenticated users, I made a GET request as follows:

```js
        const response = await fetch(`${BACKEND_URL}/canvas`, {
          method: "GET",
          credentials: "include",
        });
```

Now, the session is preserved across requests and `passport.deserializeUser` is called.

Answer (score -1):

make sure the line of code `app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));` stays below the `app.use(require('express-session')`

Comment: Why? This order doesn't matter for the issue - `deserializeUser` is not called either. Also, you get DB query on EVERY assets request. Are you sure you need to query session for your every `styles.css`?

Answer (score -1):

I open the google chrome with web-security or open incognite mode, it's working for me

```
web-security for linux /usr/bin/google-chrome-stable
--disable-web-security --user-data-dir=/home/jossnaz/.config/google-chrome/
```

Answer (score -4):

```
passport.serializeUser(
    function(user, done){
        done(null, user.id);
});

passport.deserializeUser(
    function(id, done){
        User.findById(id, function(err, user){
            if(err){
                done(err);
            }
            done(null, user);
        });
});

**> try this one**
```