# passport js missing credentials

Tags: passport.js, passport-local

Been working on this for a few hours now, pretty frustrating...

```js
router.post('/', passport.authenticate('local-signup', function(err, user, info) {
  console.log(err);
}), function(req, res){
  console.log(req);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));
});
```

When I run this, i used `console.log`, output was `{ message: 'Missing credentials' }`, which leads me to believe that the body parser is not properly parsing the body message. When I use this route however...

```js
router.post('/', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.body);
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
  res.send(JSON.stringify({ a: 1 }));
});
```

When I used `console.log`, the output was `{password: 'password', email: 'email@email.com'}`, which indicates that the `req.body` variables are being set properly and are available.

app.js

```js
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var routes = require("./config/routes.config");
var models = require("./config/models.config");
var session = require('express-session');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

models.forEach(function(model){
  GLOBAL[model] = require('./models/'+model+".model");
});
var passport = require("./config/passport.config");

app.use( bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }) );
app.use(session({ secret: 'simpleExpressMVC', resave: true, saveUninitialized: true  }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
```

Comment: I'm also facing same kind of issue and did alots of search but coundn't find any solution :-(

Answer (score 62, accepted):

I see your `req.body` contains `{password: 'password', email: 'email@email.com'}`. `email` is not what passportjs is looking for, but `username` is. You can either change your input names on your HTML/JS, or you can change the default parameters passportjs is looking for in `req.body`. You need to apply these changes where you define your strategy.

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({ // or whatever you want to use
    usernameField: 'email',    // define the parameter in req.body that passport can use as username and password
    passwordField: 'password'
  },
  function(username, password, done) { // depending on your strategy, you might not need this function ...
    // ...
  }
));
```

Answer (score 8):

In Router.post:

```
router.post('/', passport.authenticate('local-signup', {
    successRedirect: '/dashboad',
    failureRedirect: '/',
    badRequestMessage: 'Your message you want to change.', //missing credentials
    failureFlash: true
}, function(req, res, next) {
...
```

Answer (score 7):

I know there are lots of answers here, but this is as clear as it gets.

From the official passport docs

[Passportjs documentation](http://www.passportjs.org/docs/username-password/)

> "By default, LocalStrategy expects to find credentials in parameters
> named username and password. If your site prefers to name these fields
> differently, options are available to change the defaults."

So if you find yourself with this issue you have two solutions (most probably).

1. Rename your body parameters in your front-end as `username` and `password`
2. Define to your passport instance how you're going to name them with the following code:

   ```
   passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
       usernameField: 'email', //can be 'email' or 'whateveryouwant'
       passwordField: 'passwd' //same thing here
     },
     function(username, password, done) {
       // ...
     }
   ));
   ```

Comment: Thank you, you're answer further clarified and expanded upon the accepted answer, which helped wrapping my mind around the same error i was getting. Much appreciated.

Comment: Glad it helped someone. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

There could be a mistake in field-type that's why passport.js is not able to recognize the correct field and gives error .

CORRECTION: check in .ejs file if your username and password fields correctly state type.
 `type="password" id="password" name="password"`//CORRECTLY SPECIFIED.

What you might have done is : `Type:"text"` in ejs file and told passport to look for `type:"password"`

Tip : Check for spelling mistakes in type fields.
eg: `type:password` in ejs & `type:Password`

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO! Please read the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), and [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) For example there is no point in writing Silly in the begging. It might be considered offensive. Try to be as in topic as you can in your answers.

Comment: Understood! Appreciate your help .

Answer (score 1):

In my own case, the cause of this was my body-parser or express configuration, whereby inputs from the form were not received by my application. So I did this:

```
// configuring express
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));
// body-parser 
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I just miss spelled `usernameField` as `usernameFiled`.

Make sure you spell correctly `usernameField` and `passwordField`.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was spelling mistake issue.
I hade `usernameFeild: 'email',`

However, it should be `usernameField: 'email',`

Comment: if only it were that simple

Answer (score 0):

if you are using passport local mongoose as a plugin with your user model.

Try this:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email'
}, User.authenticate()));
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case add all the field inside of config works:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField : 'email',
  passwordField : 'password',
  passReqToCallback : true
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the problem when using a custom field
Here is my code before:

```
    const customFields = {
    email: 'email',
    password: 'password',
}

const verifyCallback = (email, password, done) => {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?', email, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        if (!(results.length)) {
            return done(null, false);
        }
        const user = results[0];
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, res) => {
            if (res) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        });
    }
    )
}

const strategy = new LocalStrategy(customFields, verifyCallback);
```

the problem is I used custom fields which is totally okay, but what you need to do is tell passport which field you want to change, and what to change it to

Here is the code after:

```
    const customFields = {
    usernameField : 'email',
    passwordField : 'password',
}

const verifyCallback = (email, password, done) => {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = ?', email, (err, results) => {
        if (err) {
            return done(err);
        }
        if (!(results.length)) {
            return done(null, false);
        }
        const user = results[0];
        bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, (err, res) => {
            if (res) {
                return done(null, user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        });
    }
    )
}

const strategy = new LocalStrategy(customFields, verifyCallback);
```

So in my case, I want to use email instead of username, so I told passport to replace "usernameField" with "email"

I hope that will help